# pip: "/Volumes/HD: bad interpreter: No such file or directory?

Tags: python, pip, python3

After I activated my Virtualenv i received this message:

Francos-MBP:BV francoe$source bin/activate

(BV) Francos-MBP:BV francoe$ pip freeze

-bash: /Volumes/HD 2/Projects/PythonProjects/BV/bin/pip: "/Volumes/HD: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

(BV) Francos-MBP:BV francoe$ pip install --upgrade pip
-bash: /Volumes/HD 2/Projects/PythonProjects/BV/bin/pip: "/Volumes/HD: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

At the moment I am not able set up any virtualenv ..

[p.s. I have multiple versions of python (3.5 and systems version 2.7)]

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been [discussed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911003/cant-install-via-pip-with-virtualenv):

You should create your VirtualEnv in a directory without spaces in the path. The spaces mess up the command that it is trying to run (breaking it up into additional arguments to a non-existent command).

Comment: It looks like your link points back to a Stack Overflow thread, which would be a little more "in-house".  :-)  In general though, it is better to make answers self contained because external links break.  Include the essential information here and use the link and attribution and reference.